# Setting up a Sequelize.js association with an OR condition

Tags: model, sequelize.js, associations

I have two Sequelize models that look like:

```
User = sequelize.define('User', { id: ... });
Connection = sequelize.define('Connection', {
    mentor_id: ...,
    mentee_id: ...
});
```

Where `mentor_id` and `mentee_id` are references to a User.

I would like to set up an association to get all the Connections associated with a user, based on if the user is a mentor OR mentee.

I know how to set up basic associations, but wasn't sure how to go about adding in this OR condition. Is it possible?

Comment: May I hv ur comment on the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setup the basic associations. Then query likewise

```
User.findAll({
    include: [{
       model: Connection,
       where: { 
            [Op.or] : [{mentor_id: Sequelize.col('user.id')}, {mentee_id: Sequelize.col('user.id')} ] 
       }
    }]
})
```

Hope that helps,